# Twitter BootStrap Modal and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using a twitter bootstrap in my project , i want to show the modal popup to with some text boxes and button to save the data to my BackEnd .
i use [This](https://github.com/onokumus/Bootstrap-Admin-Template) as configured template 
so its all work pretty fine , the problem is when i push the button it post back as usual and as normal thing, and the modal disappeared but its refreshing the page ....
from user experience point if view this is not fine , i want to push the button the modal fade not refreshing my page .
i tried to put it on a update panel and triggered the button and it refreshed again.
this is my code

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Help" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#helpModal">
                <i class="icon-question-sign"></i>
            </a>

    <div id="helpModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server"  ID="lnkSave" class="btn btn-default" 
                     OnClick="lnkSave_OnClick"  Text="Save"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- /.modal-content  data-dismiss="modal"  -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

no java script code here .

Answer (score 0):

There really is not point in using an asp:LinkButton if you are not going to do a postback and refresh the page. You need to use AJAX to update your values and show changes on your page if you do want to do a full postback to the server.

A jQuery setup using a jQuery click event binding to a a html  or  and a jQuery AJAX call to a web service is the step in the right direction. Looking towards an UpdatePanel as a solution only creates unnecessary complexity and guides you in the direction of not understanding web applications fully. Since this is an older question I will assume you figured things out but if you haven't I show you some code examples of how to do it.

Comment: since i didn't find a good solution i moved to use a full page not a modal or any popups :D
i tried to use the Ajax but when i use it the modal crashed.
and because i use the bootstrap i doomed to use its modal.
but any help will be very good man , Thanks in advance